# Google Play Console - An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (4ED07195)

Tags: android

I am receiving this error message when pressing the start roll-out to production button.

An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (4ED07195)

What can I do to resolved it and perform an update production roll-out on my app?

Answer (score 3):

Google chrome was the problem. I tried a browser other than chrome and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Same here. I tried on Microsoft Edge and no error. I just unload a bundle.

Answer (score 2):

FYI ~ I have resolved the issue after a few days. BUT in case someone else is facing this same error when trying to "roll-out to production". This error only occurs if you are updating an existing app that was in a APK and now trying to roll-out the "now normal" AAB file format.

The error code "4ED07195" doesn't mean much but removing those failed attempts in bundle explorer. I decided to clean the project first then do a build using the APK format and it worked!

My Steps in Android Studio 4:

Click on "Build" >> "Clean Project" >> Wait until Event log state it's complete

And Next:

Click on "Build" >> "Generate Signed Bundle/APK" >> Select "APK" & Click "Next" >> Enter your Key Store Info & Click Next >> Wait until creation >> Upload APK to google developer console.

~Hope this helps~

Answer (score 0):

For me, this error happened because I was trying to start **staged rollout** for specific version **while I have included another version in staged rollout already**.
So I got this error then I saved the rollout then I have started it normally.
But then I found that the another version has been removed from the staged rollout process. So it ended up with one version in staged rollout.

So you have to make sure before you start the rollout that you don't any other versions in the rollout process.